# How to get exact number for repeated eigenvalue in MATLAB and R

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

Following matrix has repeated eigenvalue $1$.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  8  &  -2  &   1  &  -1 \\
    23  &  -6  &   3  &  -3 \\ 
    -4  &   1  &   1  &   1 \\
    -4  &   2  &   0  &   1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

How to get $1$ instead of:
$$
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
   0.9997 + 0.0000i \\
   1.0000 + 0.0003i \\
   1.0000 - 0.0003i \\
   1.0003 + 0.0000i
\end{pmatrix}}_{\text{MATLAB: eig(A)}}
\qquad\qquad
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
   1.0002024+0.0002024i \\
   1.0002024-0.0002024i \\
   0.9997976+0.0002024i \\ 
   0.9997976-0.0002024i
\end{pmatrix}}_{\text{R: eigen(A)}}
$$

Comment: Did you use a numerical solution algorithm or the symbolic solver in MATLAB?

Comment: @Paul In Matlab, eig is a numerical eigendecomposition.

Comment: I'm not sure what it uses by default, in both cases I used a script and clicked run. I think both of those uses numerical algorithm by default @Paul

Comment: For what it's worth, the matrix is ill conditioned. In matlab, you can call `cond(M)` to find that the condition number is around 2000. Thus, we should expect numerical error. You could use `vpa` to compute it to higher precision or use a symbolic library.

Comment: @MarkMcClure vpa does not help in this case! I've tried with $vpa(eig(A),100)$, its same as above with some additional digits in tail. If I write $ev = eig(A); vpa(ev(1),100)$, I get $0.999745977694990851$.

Comment: @MarkMcClure eig(vpa(A)) adds 32 digits to Real and Imaginary parts for all 4 eigenvalues.

Comment: You just need to use full symbolic math, not variable precision arithmetic: `eig(sym(A))`. I recommend reading the excellent documentation for `sym` and `vpa`.

Comment: @horchler, eig(sym(A)) is perfect, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're working with floating point arithmetic, so unless you use a symbolic package, there's going to be some incorrect digits.  You could set a tolerance and round to the nearest whole number, but that may impact your computation of other eigenvalues.  In Matlab, you could round to the second digit by way of:

```
round(1.003 + 0.0031i,2)
```

Edit: why the downvote, was something I said incorrect?

Comment: Yes, round(eig(A),2) gives me all 1 :).

Comment: You are correct, I've accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

For Octave users, [OctSymPy](https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy) is a symbolic package which try to be compatible with SMT unless [otherwise specified](https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy/blob/master/matlab_smt_differences.md). It also claims to work on Matlab, but I don't use Matlab, so I cannot test it. (Please [file a bug](https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy/issues) if it doesn't!)

To run your example, simply type (This should also work on SMT):

```
eig(sym([8 -2 1 -1; 23 -6 3 -3; -4 1 1 1; -4 2 0 1]))
```

A screenshot showing the result:
[image]

Feel free to ask if you don't understand something.

Comment: Never used. Does it support scripting like MATLAB and R?

Comment: Its like who knows matlab knows octave! not bad ...

Comment: @EmonHaque It does, it supports [function files and script files](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/Functions-and-Scripts.html#Functions-and-Scripts).